# Swift - Fetching multiple one-many values for loop - cast to unrelated type

Tags: swift, for-loop, core-data

I'm attempting to fetch data from my one-many relationship, however I cannot access their values unless I cast the fetch data to an array.

My relationships are as so:

[image]

I am saving as so:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("save")
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let workout = Workout(context: context)
    workout.name = workoutName.text
    workout.noOfSets = Int16(setsStepper.value)

    for index in 0..<setsVal {
        let sets = Sets(context: context)
        let test = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: test) as! RepsTableViewCell
        sets.repAmount = Int16(cell.repsStepper.value)
        print(sets.repAmount)
        workout.addToSets(sets)
    }
    try! context.save()
}
```

I am fetching as so:

```
func fetch() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Workout")

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for index in result as! [Workout] {
            print(index.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
            print(index.value(forKey: "noOfSets") as! Int16)
            /* This line throws error */
            /* Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated
               type '[Sets]' alwaysfails */
            for ind in index.sets as! [Sets] {
                print(ind.repAmount)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("failed")
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of why index.sets is of type NSSet.
The generated core-data properties include:

```
extension Workout {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Workout> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Workout>(entityName: "Workout")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var noOfSets: Int16
@NSManaged public var sets: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for sets
extension Workout {

@objc(addSetsObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToSets(_ value: Sets)

@objc(removeSetsObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromSets(_ value: Sets)

@objc(addSets:)
@NSManaged public func addToSets(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeSets:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromSets(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

I'm unsure of why the auto generated core-data properties contain types of NSSet.

Is there a way for me to cast index.sets to an array so I can access the individual set values belonging to the specified workout in the previous for loop (index in result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm unsure of why index.sets is of type NSSet

Because that is what a one-to-many relationship gives you. This is very efficient and powerful. Don't worry, be happy.

> I cannot access their values unless I cast the fetch data to an array

I don't see why you "cannot access their values". You have the set. It contains elements. Those are the values.

> ```
>         /* This line throws error */
>         /* Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated
>            type '[Sets]' alwaysfails */
>         for ind in index.sets as! [Sets] {
> ```

You cannot cast `index.sets` to a `[Sets]` because that is not what it is. It is a `Set<Sets>`.

```
        for ind in index.sets as! Set<Sets> {
```

(You could *coerce* `index.sets` to a `[Sets]`, but there is no need to do so. Just use the Set you are given. A Set has no order but you can still cycle thru it, get properties from its elements, etc. If you need to sort it you can, as an array, but I don't see any need for that given your model.)

Comment: And next time would you please not call an entity Sets???? What a confusing name.

Comment: How would you suggest I sort the array?
I need it in the order I added the elements.
Is this possible if I added the elements to an NSSet?

Comment: You would need to have a time stamp or index number as an attribute of this entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the set.

If you really want to use array instead, try this

```
if let arr = index.sets?.allObjects as? [Sets]
{
   // do something here
}
```

According to Apple's documentation, .allObjects is

> An array containing the set’s members, or an empty array if the set has no members.